# Hard-Delete Objects Using the Force.com Migration tool

Tags: metadata-api, migration-tool

Is there a way to hard-delete custom objects using the Force.com migration tool? When you deploy a DestructiveChanges payload, the objects are "soft-deleted" and not erased from the platform. This creates an issue when you subsequently try to push back in those objects.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hmm, the documentation doesn't mention hard deletes. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/daas_destructive_changes.htm

Comment: Yeah, went up and down the documentation about a hundred times. :)

Comment: Are you sure that's the "push back" that's causing the error? Deleted objects get `API_Name_del__c` instead of `API_Name__c`. Maybe you're trying to delete an object while there's one with same name in the bin already?

Comment: I'm deleting the objects which is then creating the Object_del__c. That's what I mean by a soft delete. I need a full erase of the object so that I can re-deploy it which would include removing the Object_del__c.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A hidden gem in the Metadata API **deploy** operation takes a [DeployOptions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deploy.htm#deploy_options) structure, in it is a **purgeOnDelete** setting that will do what you need!

> **purgeOnDelete.** If true, the deleted components in the destructiveChanges.xml manifest file aren't stored in the Recycle Bin. Instead, they become immediately eligible for deletion.
>   This field is available in API version 22.0 and later.
>   This option only works in Developer Edition or sandbox organizations; it doesn't work in production organizations.

**Extending Salesforce Migration Tool to Support PurgeOnDelete.**. For some reason this excellent feature has still not been exposed by the Salesforce Migration Tools via the sf:deploy Ant Task. However with a bit of Java skills you can create a new deploy Ant Task by extending the current one, to expose the attribute to your Ant build scripts, for example...

```
<taskdef name="deploypurge" classname="com.salesforce.ant.SFDCDeployPurge" classpath="../lib/ant-salesforce.jar"/>
<deploypurge purgeOnDelete="true" username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.server}" deployRoot="stage/deploy" singlePackage="true" runAllTests="false" rollbackOnError="false" allowMissingFiles="true" maxPoll="2000" pollWaitMillis="5000"/>
```

**Prebuilt ant-salesforce.jar with deploypurge in it.** You can download a modified **ant-salesforce.jar** here from the FinancialForce.com Developers Github [repo](https://github.com/financialforcedev/df12-deployment-tools/tree/master/lib) (be warned this is API v22.0, though you can use it to deploy code at any version).

**Building your own extended ant-salesforce.jar.** If you want rebuild a new version, then you need to download this Java [class](https://github.com/financialforcedev/df12-deployment-tools/blob/master/DF12Tools/src/com/salesforce/ant/SFDCDeployPurge.java), compile it, unzip the ant-salesforce.jar (rename .jar to .zip), put it in and zip it back up again and your all set!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Your very welcome, I'm off to raise a Salesforce Idea to get this exposed by default now! :)

Comment: Here it is, even included the code change to make! https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kqeFAAQ

Answer (score 5):

This is now exposed in the Force.com migration tool by default. You may now use `purgeOnDelete="true"` in your `build.xml` to permanently delete your destructive changes. This only works on developer/sandbox orgs, and does not work on production orgs.

Example:

```
  <sf:deploy purgeOnDelete="true" username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="mypkg" rollbackOnError="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of. Whenever I have needed to do a hard delete, it's been a manual step after destructive changes get deployed.

If there is a workaround for your particular situation, it probably involves changing the name of the object/field you are (re-)deploying, but I couldn't give more specific advice without more info.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought:  could you script something to do this with CURL type requests to the salesforce web UI?

Comment: Seems to me like this would be a massively complicated option, have you ever tried something like this?