# Delete CustomField using Tooling API

Tags: custom-field, tooling-api, create

i can correctly create CustomFields on my account using Tooling API, but i can't delete them the same way.

The documentation is not clear about this part and, if i try to use a `DELETE` call on the CustomField endpoint, i receive a `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` error.

So the question is: how can i delete a CustomField using Tooling API?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You would need Metadata API to delete a field. Due to the documentation, CustomField doesn't support DELETE method

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the Tooling API to delete CustomField metadata. Per the [Tooling API documentation on `CustomField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customfield.htm), there is no delete option. Only `Query`, `GET`, `POST`, & `PATCH`.

If you need to delete CustomField metadata through an API, then using [**deploy()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm) through the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm) is likely the way to go. You will need to deploy destructive changes to the org. An example destructiveChanges.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>deletingfield</fullName>
    <types>
        <members>Account.Custom_Field__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <version>53.0</version>
</Package>
```

If you set `purgeOnDelete="true"` then the deleted metadata skips the recycle bin and gets permanently removed, rather than `Custom_Field__c` turning into `Custom_Field__del`. Details on this: [Hard-Delete Objects Using the Force.com Migration tool](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12709/hard-delete-objects-using-the-force-com-migration-tool)